# Multivalued Dependency Axioms

Tags: database, relational-algebra

According to [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency#Interesting_properties) on Wikipedia, the five rules (complementation, augmentation, transition, replication and coalescence) and three Armstrong's axioms make up a sound and complete set of rules for multivalued dependencies.

I am having trouble proving the intersection rule from these rules. The intersection rule is

> (X ↠ Y and X ↠ Z) implies X ↠ Y ∩ Z

It seems like I don't have the right intuition about these rules (or multivalued dependencies). I have proved the intersection rule directly from the definition of multivalued dependency though.

Comment: It's a bit iffy whether this question is on topic, ["the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  This might be a better fit on one of the other sites.

Comment: @BradKoch Thanks for the suggestion. I do not have enough reputation to migrate the question by myself. Should I delete it and create another one on a different site? (Which site should I go to?)

Comment: Re intuition: X->>Y in T on attributes XYZ means T = T projected on XY JOIN T projected on XZ. You can losslessly decompose T into projections XY and XZ. The rows satisfy XY(x,...,y,...) AND XZ(x,...,z,...).

Comment: @philipxy Thank you. From the join point of view, it is quite intuitive. Join dependency is also intuitive in that sense. But from the axiomatic perspective, I don't quite have the intuition...

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suspect the formal definitions on the wiki article are wrong.

In fact, I think that the definitions as stated there even allow to prove that if an MVD A -->> B holds, then it is impossible for any MVD A -->> S to hold with S a proper subset of B.  And that would make it impossible for your intersection theorem to hold in general.

Comment: Can you give more detail on how you show that A ↠ B implies impossibility of A ↠ S for any proper subset S of B (from possibly flawed definitions)?

Comment: For the time being, no.  That's why I said "suspect" and "think".  I'll look more deeply into this when I have the time.